# USB Vendor ID for Aakash tablets

Tags: android, usb-debugging

To enable USB debugging(android development using eclipse on ubuntu), we need a USB vendor ID of the device. Does anyone know for Aakash(manufacturer: Datawind), because Datawind is not there on the list by Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 Steps:

- make sure, tablet is **unplugged**
- run `lsusb` and note output
- plugin tablet
- run `lsusb` again

the output will differ by one line - this gives you VendorID and DeviceID of the tablet