# Android ADT Device not recognized - Aakash Tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am developing an android application and want to test it on the my tablet. The tablet is shown on eclipse but this is the scenario [image]

This tablet is supplied to me as a part of my project . It has a low end specs such as 512MB RAM , low internal memory etc.. I can run the app on my samsung smartphone but the aim of my project is to develop a customized app for the tablet(This tablet is called Aakash Tablet - a subsidized tablet by Govt of India for students)

I have enabled the debugging mode also turned the usb storage on when prompted.I am developing application on Linux . The Specs of the tablet are as follows:

Model No: T-A13
Android version: 4.0.4
Kernel Version : 3.0.8

After browsing the net , I came to conclusion that the drivers may not exist but don't know how do i get them . My work is stalled because of this ,Please help

Comment: Do you have the Google USB drivers installed?

Comment: @ars-longa-vita-brevis From the developer site , we can see that Google USB Drivers are required only for Windows Platform and in my case I use Linux(Ubuntu flavour)

Comment: yes, that's correct. i'm sorry i don't have any idea what could be wrong. adb seems to recognize that a device is connected or else nothing would have shown up in the device chooser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the drivers

http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/

Get usb vendor id to be used while adding driver

[USB Vendor ID for Aakash tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853005/usb-vendor-id-for-aakash-tablets)